# Bug in d3.js Stacked chart morphing

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I've created a stacked chart animation/update app. However there appears to be NaN values being passed into the y and height variables. I am unsure as to what is wrong. If you toggle the data the charts eventually fill up.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/15/)

but the problem may occur first in setting the yaxis

```
                 svg.select("g.y")
                  .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                      .call(methods.yAxis);
```

It looks like something goes wrong in the bar rect enter/exit code.

```
                //_morph bars       


                var bar = stacks.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(function(d) {
                        return d.blocks; 
                    });

                // Enter
                bar.enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(d.y1); })
                    .attr("width", methods.x.rangeBand())
                    .style("fill", function(d) { return methods.color(d.name); });

                // Update
                bar
                    .attr("y", methods.height)
                    .attr("height", initialHeight)
                    .attr("width", methods.x.rangeBand())
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .attr("x", function(d) { return methods.x(d.Label); })
                    .attr("width", methods.x.rangeBand())
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(d.y1); })
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return methods.y(d.y0) - methods.y(d.y1); })

                // Exit
                bar.exit()
                    .transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(d.y1); })
                    .attr("height", function(d) { methods.y(d.y0) - methods.y(d.y1); })
                    .remove();


                //__morph bars
```

Comment: Can you not distils the problem down in your JSFiddle? i.e. the simplest set of code which exhibits the issue? You might even find the problem whilst creating it!

Comment: I am not sure what is creating the issue. The issue crops up when trying to provide data to multiple charts. Somewhere the y data is malfunctioning for the other charts - but comes back after toggling a set of updates. e.g. works fine for just 1 instance of stacked chart - http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/17/ - its as if the plugin is not catering for other instances well - like something needs to be reset or not set initially for other charts

Comment: enabling it to handle 2 charts - breaks the 2nd chart - sometimes - http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/18/

Comment: Your data structure is all messed up -- look closely at your output for 'clone' console log: you've got five "blocks" in each stack, not three, with the fourth and fifth being named "blocks" and "total", and all their values and your overall "total" being NaN.

Comment: And I would like to strongly second @ChristopherHackett's comment.  The code you post is always incredibly complex, with methods calling other methods so it is very difficult to follow.  When you break things down to really simple examples, you can often find the error yourself, and if not then other people can help you much more easily.

Comment: So its likely to be the data being pumped into each chart. Somewhere in the method its not being uniquely added to each chart. I had a base version of it, working for one chart - but this problem has come about by placing it into a plugin - for use with having multiple charts - each with different data sets.

Comment: ok taken it out of the plugin - trashed the setup method - http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/30/

Comment: I've tried to remove more unused methods - http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/34/ and comment the code

Comment: This code seems to work with one instance of the stacked chart - there are no NAN values coming out of it. http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/39/

Comment: I've added it back into my plugin and its fixed the initial section of the charts. http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/42/ - however I think its breaking still on update - it could be where the domain is set - as if the data is smeared on other charts. The bars can represent different things on other charts and maybe somewhere down the line - bagels, jam - does not correspond to burger,peanuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the anomaly by deleting data in the update function. I'm not sure why though the data is not unique - it looks like if the data is the same - as the last chart - it gets modified accordingly and used again for its next chart. Is there a better way of cleaning this up - I've tried to keep objects unique and clean by cloning/splicing but maybe that is contributing towards the problem.

delete d.blocks;
delete d.total;

http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/53/

```
update: function(data){
                        methods.el = this;
                        var selector = methods.el["selector"];

                        data.forEach(function(d) {
                              delete d.blocks;
                            delete d.total;
                        });

                        methods.animateBars(selector, data);                         
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've managed to narrow down the problem to the setDBlock function.

It appears if another chart has the same set of data, it takes on additional object parameters inside the dblock obj.

http://jsfiddle.net/XnngU/44/

I'm not sure at this stage as to how to clean it up. But I have isolated this via a legend and a function.

```
setDBlocks: function(incomingdata){
                        var data = incomingdata.slice(0);

                        methods.color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Label"; }));

                        data.forEach(function(d) {
                            console.log("D", d);

                            var y0 = 0;

                            if(d["blocks"] == undefined){
                                d.blocks = methods.color.domain().map(function(name) {
                                    var val = d[name];

                                    if(isNaN(val)){
                                        val = 0;
                                    }

                                    return {name: name, values: val, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +val};
                                });
                            }

                            d.total = d.blocks[d.blocks.length - 1].y1;
                        });                 
                    }
```

Comment: What is causing the bug - when the data is the same for more than one chart. Is the same data being modified and then pushed to another chart?